# why this concatenation is resulting in "208" instead of "20010"

Tags: concatenation

```
class Jspiders
{   

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        System.out.println("number is "+20+010);

    }
}
```

and also when I try to print "2001" it results in 201 ??

Comment: Please provide your programming language as a tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really cool! The language is java and I just tried it out. I didn't know java can read number literals other than decimals but I never really tried. It looks like it's because it thinks that 010 is a base 8 number and in octet form

010 = 8 
01 = 1
so 20 + 010 will give you 208 (not 28 because it's doing string concatenation if you put in (20+010) then it will print 28)
and 20 + 01 gives you 201
I also played around a bit and notices if you do 20 + 0xA it will give you 2010 (0xA is 10 in hex). 
So that's why you're getting those results.

Comment: then it could read binary also ...if I put 3 digit starting with 0 and its not octal then it gives me error "the literal 080 of int type is out of range " but when i put 02 it removes zero n take 2 it should give the similar type of error too.

Answer (score 0):

010 is an octal number representation  (base 8)

The operator + applies to the type of the leftmost operand, which is a string and therefore + is the operator for string concatenation.

```
System.out.println("number is "+(20+010));
```

will give you a different answer involving integer addition of 2 numbers, the leftmost part of (20+010) being a number.

Comment: then how does System.out.println concatenation actually works ??

Comment: println does NOT do any concatenation. println() function has a single parameter. It can be an integer, it can be a floating point, it can be a string ...  you are providing a single parameter as a string+int+int. Then the language interpreter converts your expression into a single operand with the type of the leftmost operand, and pass the result to println.